# Logging into Oracle 11g database is denied by getting username and password from properties file in Apache Camel

Tags: xml, oracle11g, apache-camel

I am trying get values of user name and password from .properties file and trying to login to oracle database.I am following all the syntax specified but oracle database is denying access to database.I am giving my properties place-holder configuration and database bean.

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:DB.properties" />
         </bean>


   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
  </bean>
```

Below i am providing my .properties file...

```
db.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe
db.username=system
db.password=1234
```

Though i am following all the correct syntax i am getting problem to connect to database.Help in resolving this issue.

Comment: 'Denying access' is a bit vague - exactly what error do you get? Why are you connecting to the powerful `system` account instead of your own account?

Comment: I am getting this error exactly Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initDatabase' defined in file [C:\Desktop\camel-example-sql\target\classes\META-INF\spring\camel-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied). I am using express edition oracle 11g for POC purpose

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using properties bean provided by Apache Camel in Camel-Core jar.I used context:property-placeholder it cleared my error. In addition to it,i added the following xmlns and xsi:schemalocation..

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

 xsi:schemaLocation="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
**http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">****
```